# Graphing many lines on time-series with a condition, and same date on all lines

Tags: r

Using ggplot, how do you graph each state as a line on a plot, and y axis is money, x axis is date. The issue is that I do not know how to graph, when there are many of the same date for each state. Also, I need to add a label California on the end of the line of each line.

Do not waste your time and do the whole thing, just show me a short example and I can do the rest. I really appreciate it.

Date          State  Money

1. 2020-09-01  CA 10
2. 2020-10-01  CA 11
3. 2020-11-01  CA 12
4. 2020-12-01  CA 13
5. 2020-09-01  MA 3
6. 2020-10-01  MA 4
7. 2020-11-01  MA 5
8. 2020-12-01  MA 4
9. 2020-09-01  AR 6
10. 2020-10-01 AR 5
11. 2020-11-01 AR 4
12. 2020-12-01 AR 6

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = Doses[which(States == "CA")]

Error length differing (The problem is there are 10 sets of the same date, when I just want to plot one line which use only one similar set of date)

Comment: Your `aes` are inconsistent. `x` uses all rows in the data frame, `y` only those for California. Either (a) filter the data frame before calling `ggplot` ( to get only the California line) or (b) use a  custom legend to suppress l entries for all states apart from California.

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(Date, Money, color = State)) + geom_line()`. Just group by `State` using the `color` aesthetic. This is probably a duplicate. If there are many of the same date for each state, maybe `geom_point` and a smoother layer is better, or, for instance, `stat_function` with `fun = median`.